# ReSharper 'Show Covering Tests' is greyed out

Tags: c#, resharper-2017

I have VS 2017 Professional with Resharper Ultimate 2017.1

The 'Show Covering Tests' menu item is greyed out and pressing CTRL+ALT+K, T gives "The key combination (CTRL+ALT+K, T) is bound to command (ReSharper_ShowTestsCoveringEditorContext) which is not currently available".

Which settings do I have to tinker with to enable this functionality?

I have all the relevant products installed:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to separately install dotCover for that to work.

Comment: @Inertiaboogie I have dotCover installed

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem by executing ReSharper->Unit Tests->Cover All Tests from Solution.

You would think R# would do this for you, or at least pop up a message telling you it was necessary, but there you go :(

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue - the "Cover Unit Tests" option in the ReSharper menu is greyed out. However I found that you can right-click in the "Unit Test Explorer" window and the option is available from there. Seems like a bug in ReSharper.